# Rails collection select with Enum values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the below code which displays a dropdown to the user containing a list of possible streams.

```
Select Stream ID: 
<%=  f.select :stream_id, Log.stream_types.keys.to_a.map { |w| [w.humanize, w] } %>
```

The enum is defined in the Log model as shown below and the Log model has a field named stream_type_id as shown below.

```
enum stream_type: {P1: 1, P2: 2, P3: 3, P4: 4, SR: 5, PASM1: 6, PASM2: 7, AME: 8, AD: 9, Training: 10, Vacation: 11, Sick_Leave: 12, Comp_off: 13, PH_OH: 14 }
```

When i display the page html code, the below is shown:

```
<select id="log_stream_id" name="log[stream_id]"><option  value="P1">P1</option>
<option value="P2">P2</option>
<option value="P3">P3</option>
<option value="P4">P4</option>
<option value="SR">Sr</option>
<option value="PASM1">Pasm1</option>
<option value="PASM2">Pasm2</option>
<option value="AME">Ame</option>
<option value="AD">Ad</option>
<option value="Training">Training</option>
<option value="Vacation">Vacation</option>
<option value="Sick_Leave">Sick leave</option>
<option value="Comp_off">Comp off</option>
<option value="PH_OH">Ph oh</option></select>
```

How can i write the code that the integer value corresponding to the selected stream is passed when the user submits the form and not the String value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `Log.stream_types.keys.to_a.map { |w| [w.humanize, w] }` to `Log.stream_types.map { |k, v| [k.humanize, v] }`. The second argument of `select` is an array of option arrays. The first and second elements of an option array are the text and the value of an option element respectively.